# shortest distance of $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $3x + 4y = 12$

Tags: optimization, circles, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $3x + 4y = 12$

line from origin with gradient $\frac{4}{3}$ intersect circle at $(\frac{6}{5} , \frac{8}{5}) $.
intersect $3x + 4y = 12$ at $(\frac{36}{25}, \frac{36}{25})$.
so distance is $\sqrt{{(\frac{36}{25}- \frac{6}{5})}^2 + {(\frac{36}{25}- \frac{8}{5})}^2} = \frac{\sqrt{52}}{25}$

but my answer is wrong. Where am i wrong?

Comment: The line intyersects the circle at $(\frac65,\frac85)$ for me.

Comment: you still have the point where the line from the origin (with slope $\frac43$) intersects $3x+4y=12$ wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to find the intersection, that is no need for quadratics.  The normal to $y=-\frac34x+3$ through the origin is given by the equation $y=\frac43x$; determine the intersection point of both to find that the distance from the line to the origin is $\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+\left(-\frac34\right)^2}}=\frac{12}{5}$.  Hence the distance from the circle to the line is $\frac{12}{5}-2$.

NB: In general the distance from $y=mx+b$ to the origin is $\frac{|b|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$

Comment: yes. why i didn't notice it..

Comment: We are all only human beings ...

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct.

You need to redo your calculation of intersects.

You have the  point $(\frac {6}{5}, \frac {6}{5})$ on the line $y=\frac {4}{3} x$ which does not make sense.

Comment: yes, it doesn't make sense. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Using coordinate geometry,

Any point on the circle $P(2\cos t,2\sin t)$

Distance of $P$ from the line $$\dfrac{|3(2\cos t)+4(2\sin t)-12|}5$$

Now $-\sqrt{6^2+8^2}\le 6\cos t+8\sin t\le?$

Comment: So answer must be $\frac{2}{5}$ I guess?

Comment: ok, thank you..  but not really got it..

Comment: @Lifeforbetter for any line $ax+by+c=0$ and any point (h,k), the perpendicular of the line from (h,k) is $\frac{|ah+bk+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter any point on the circle is of the form $(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))$. So we have to minimize the perpendicular distance. That is what the answer does.

Comment: but, how to minimize it..

Comment: @LifeForBetter $$-10-12\le 6\cos t+8\sin t-12\le10-12$$ right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$x_c^2+y_c^2=4$$ and $$3x_s+4y_s=12$$ then $$d=\sqrt{(x_c-x_s)^2+(y_c-y_s)^2}$$ you can eliminate two variables.

Comment: yes. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$3x=12-4y=4(3-y)$

WLOG any point on the line $P(4m,3-3m)$

$\dfrac43=\dfrac{3-3m-0}{4m-0}$

$m=?$

Can you find the distance of $P$ from the origin

Subtract the length of the radius from the distance

Answer (score 0):

Let $c$ be a real number such that $3x+4y=c$ has common points $(x,y)$ with the circle and parallel to $3x+4y=12$.

Thus, by C-S we obtain:
$$|c|=|3x+4y|\leq\sqrt{(3^2+4^2)(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{25\cdot4}=10,$$ which says that
$3x+4y=10$ is a tangent to the circle,

which is parallel to the line $3x+4y=12$ and  nearest to this line.

Id est, the needed distance it's:
$$\frac{|12-10|}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=\frac{2}{5}.$$